# Cannot Create VIew on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view

It's Possible to Create this VIEW on MySQL? The problem is with the variables. I can't find a way around it.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_ranking AS 

SELECT rank.ativid_id, rank.user_id, b.nome, rank.quant

FROM
(SELECT user_id, ativid_id, quant, 

    @ativ_rank := IF(@current_ativ = ativid_id, @ativ_rank + 1, 1) AS ativ_rank,
    @current_ativ := ativid_id 

FROM (SELECT ativid_id, user_id, COUNT(user_id) as quant FROM tb_registro_ativ

    GROUP BY ativid_id, user_id) atividade
    ORDER BY ativid_id, quant DESC

) rank INNER JOIN tb_usuarios b ON rank.user_id = b.user_id

WHERE ativ_rank <= 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define variables with view creation.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

> A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.
>
> The SELECT statement ***cannot*** refer to ***system variables*** or ***user-defined
>   variables***.
>
> Within a stored program, the SELECT statement cannot refer to program
>   parameters or local variables.
>
> The SELECT statement cannot refer to prepared statement parameters.
>
> Any table or view referred to in the definition must exist. After the
>   view has been created, it is possible to drop a table or view that the
>   definition refers to. In this case, use of the view results in an
>   error. To check a view definition for problems of this kind, use the
>   CHECK TABLE statement.

I suggest you use a stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 1):

Views are severely limited in MySQL.  You cannot use variables and you cannot use subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

Your query is quite complicated.  You *can* use subqueries in the `SELECT`, and that often makes it possible to calculate ranks -- at least on small tables.  In your case, you might need a series of views to accomplish what you want.